# how to set a simple field in openerp custom module

Tags: python

I have some code like this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields,osv
                                                         
import time

class formview(osv.osv):

        _columns = {'name': fields.char('name',size=64) }


formview()
```

But I get an error:

```
  _columns = {'name': fields.char('name',size=64) }
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple and most common issue for new developers.

You have to configure your IDE with 4 space instead of tab.
Once you configure it will not show this error.

If you using ubuntu then use gedit much batter and easy for openerp developement.

To right now resolve your issue, use four space instead of one tab.

OpenERP follow indentation by four space.